# Symfony fatal error on vanilla 2.5.5

Tags: php, symfony

I've just installed vanilla Symfony 2.5.5 using composer and got fatal error exception by just visiting `app_dev.php`:

`FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Or in /var/www/symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Binary/Or.php line 13`

and also

`Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Sub' not found in /var/www/symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php on line 52`

I'm totally puzzled. I've grepped through the symfony but didn't find anything suspicious. This never happened to me before and frankly, I don't have idea what might be the cause of this.

Comment: Did you use composer create-project or did you add the symfony dependency to an existing setup?

Comment: I did use composer create-project: `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ./ "2.5.*"`

Comment: Do you get the same message when you run app/console?

Comment: @Cerad app/console seems to work fine. I'm also able to see the "welcome" page, well except the web debug toolbar that crashes with message: ***An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error).***

Comment: Strange.  php version?  And of course clear the cache.  And this really was new?  You did not try to install into a directory holding a previous symfony project?

Comment: PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u14. Maybe not the newest one, but still should work fine. Cache cleared dozen times. Fresh install to an empty dir. I even wiped out everything and reinstalled. Still the same. First Fatal error is `Cannot redeclare class Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Or` and then immediately next one `Class 'Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Sub' not found`.